# Remove duplicate linebreaks in a string

Tags: python, regex, line-endings

I have some files which could use `\r`, `\n`, or `\r\n` as their line break mode.

I am trying to change all of them to `\r\n`, and remove consecutive line breaks. In theory, this is easy, and any number of [very simple regexes](http://regex101.com/r/hC2dD7) should work.

In practice, though,

```py
text = re.sub(
    reg_exp,
    r'\r\n',
    text)
```

on this string (showing line-ending characters),

```html
<ul>␍␊
␍␊
<li><a href="#">link</a></li>␍␊
␍␊
<li><a href="#">link</a></li>␍␊
<li><a href="#">link</a></li>␍␊
␍␊
<li><a href="#">link</a></li>␍␊
␍␊
</ul>␍␊
```

- for `reg_exp = r'[\r\n]{2,}'`, makes

  ```html
  <ul>␍
  ␍␊
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li>␍
  ␍␊
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li>␍␊
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li>␍
  ␍␊
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li>␍
  ␍␊
  </ul>␍␊
  ```
- for `reg_exp = r'[\r\n]+'`, makes

  ```html
  <ul>␍
  ␍␊
     <li><a href="#">link</a></li>␍
  ␍␊
     <li><a href="#">link</a></li>␍
  ␍␊
     <li><a href="#">link</a></li>␍
  ␍␊
     <li><a href="#">link</a></li>␍
  ␍␊
  </ul>␍
  ␍␊
  ```

and I cannot figure out why.

Is my regex not matching the `\r` for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was when Python **wrote the string** back to the Windows file system. It made some unexpected decisions about what to do with line endings. Specifically, it decided that:

- `\r` should write `\r`
- `\n` should write **`\r\n` (What!?)**

Both [zmo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21536166/241211) and [Louis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21536501/241211) have answers that work in the Python console, as did the code in the question, it turns out.

For completeness, this is what the `write()` looked like:

```
with open(file_name, 'r+') as f:
    text = f.read()

    # text = re.sub(...)

    f.seek(0)
    f.write(text)
    f.truncate()
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if you correctly copy/pasted your example string, but there is an extra character between each occurrence of the `\r\n` string, so basically the following regex:

```py
re.sub(r'(\r\n.?)+', r'\r\n', text)
```

will remove any of:

```
\r\n\r\n
\r\n \r\n
\r\n\n\r\n
\r\n\r\n\r\n
\r\n \r\n \r\n
\r\n\r\n \r\n
\r\n \r\n\r\n
...
```

full test:

```py
>>> text =  """<ul>\r\n \r\n <li><a href="#">link</a></li>\r\n \r\n <li><a href="#">link</a></li>\r\n <li><a href="#">link</a></li>\r\n \r\n <li><a href="#">link</a></li>\r\n \r\n </ul>\r\n"""
>>> print text
<ul>
 
 <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
 
 <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
 
 <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
 
 </ul>
>>> print re.sub(r'(\r\n.?)+', r'\r\n', text).__repr__()
'<ul>\r\n<li><a href="#">link</a></li>\r\n<li><a href="#">link</a></li>\r\n<li><a href="#">link</a></li>\r\n<li><a href="#">link</a></li>\r\n</ul>\r\n'
>>> print re.sub(r'(\r\n.?)+', r'\r\n', text)
<ul>
<li><a href="#">link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

The following regexp:

```py
print re.sub(r'([\r\n]+.?)+', r'\r\n', text)
```

works as well and can support `\n`-only strings.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `splitlines()` on a string and join the lines with `'\r\n'`.

```py
>>> text = '<ul>\r\n \r\n <li><a href="#">link</a></li>\r\n \r\n <li><a href="#">link</a></li>\r\n <li><a href="#">link</a></li>\r\n \r\n <li><a href="#">link</a></li>\r\n \r\n </ul>\r\n\r \n'
>>> print '\r\n'.join([x for x in text.splitlines() if x.strip()])
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
 </ul>
```